# How to create a <ul> based on an array number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a GitHub profile searcher and what i'm trying to do is:

- Get the user Avatar
- Get the user Name
- Get the user Repositories

I'm having troubles with the last one.

What i can't figure out is how to create a UL based in the user repos quantity.

What i have HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Github Profile Searcher</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="github-profile.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="username-input" class="username-input">
        Username:
        <input class="username-input-text" type="text" />
    </div>

    <div id="github-profile" class="github-profile">
        <div class="github-profile-avatar">
            <span class="github-profile-username">mmckalan</span>
        </div>
        <div class="github-profile-name">       
            Alan Mac Cormack
        </div>
        <div class="github-profile-location">
            Napoli,NA
        </div>
        <div class="github-profile-stats">
            <div class="github-profile-stat">
                <i class="icon github-icon-repo" /></i>
                <span id = "github-profile-repo-count" class="github-profile-repo-count">50</span>
            </div>
            <div class="github-profile-stat">
                <i class="icon github-icon-gist" /></i>
                <span class="github-profile-gist-count">12</span>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="github-profile.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var usernameInput = document.querySelector('#username-input .username-input-text');

 var emptyUser = {
        login: "",
        name: "",
        location: "",
        public_repos: "",
        public_gists: "",
        avatar_url: "notfound.png"
};

usernameInput.addEventListener('change', function(event){
var ghReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
ghReq.addEventListener("load", updateProfileBadge);
ghReq.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/users/" + usernameInput.value);
ghReq.send();
});

function updateProfileBadge() {
var response = JSON.parse(this.reponseText);
if (response.message === "Not Found") {
    updateDomWithUser(emptyUser);
} else {
    updateDomWithUser(response);
}
}

function updateDomWithUser(user) {
var profile = document.getElementById('github-profile');
profile.querySelector('.github-profile-username').innerText = user.login;
profile.querySelector('.github-profile-name').innerText = user.name;
profile.querySelector('.github-profile-location').innerText = user.location;
profile.querySelector('.github-profile-repo-count').innerText = 
user.public_repos;
profile.querySelector('.github-profile-gist-count').innerText = 
user.public_gists;
profile.querySelector('.github-profile-avatar')
       .style.backgroundImage = "url(" + user.avatar_url + ")";
}


updateDomWithUser(emptyUser);

var quantity = document.getElementById('github-profile-repo-count');

var ul = document.createElement("ul");
document.body.appendChild(ul);
```

What i'm trying to do is something like this:

[image]

The quantity of LI is based on the number given by **user.public_repos**

But it has to fit to the user repos quantity, so i don't know how to solve it.

Could u please give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, call to "https://api.github.com/users/NAME" would give you only the number of public respos, not names or stars. For that, you need to call "https://api.github.com/users/NAME/repos" - it may be chained after the first call.

Still, creating X list elements without data is quite easy:

```
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
document.body.appendChild(ul);
for (var i = 0; i < user.public_repos; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = 'example text';
  ul.appendChild(li)
}
```

Or, if you'll get the repos data itself, in form of array:

```
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
document.body.appendChild(ul);
repos.forEach((repo)=>{
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = repo.name;
  ul.appendChild(li)
})
```

Another thing - it's better to write

```
public_repos: 0,
```

than empty string.

Comment: any hint on how to adapt this to my code? I'm pretty new in JS :(

Answer (score 0):

To create a list of repos, you just have to loop through the JSON data returned by `/users/{my_user}/repos`. In your case, you need two Ajax calls:

1. The first one gives you information about the user
2. The second one gives you information about the user repos

Here is a minimal working example with my repositories:

```js
function get(endpoint, callback) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

  req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (this.status === 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        callback(data);
      } else {
        console.log(this.status, this.statusText);
      }
    }
  };
  
  req.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com' + endpoint, true);
  req.send(null);
}

function handleUser(data) {
  var html = '';
  html += '<li>' + data.login + '</li>';
  html += '<li>' + data.name + '</li>';
  document.querySelector('#user > ul').innerHTML = html;
  
  get('/users/Badacadabra/repos', handleUserRepos);
}

function handleUserRepos(data) {
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    html += '<li>' + data[i].name + '</li>';
  }
  document.querySelector('#repos > ul').innerHTML = html;
}

get('/users/Badacadabra', handleUser);
```

```html
<div id="user">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="repos">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Could you please give me a hint on how adapt this to my code?

I want to get the data of the user that i am writing in the input text:

        <input class="username-input-text" type="text" />

Comment: You can set a `keyup` event listener on your `input`, get the `value` in your handler, then perform Ajax requests with the given name...